# 9-patch issues with ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am facing issues with my 9 patch images with a custom `View` component.

The way I am using the image is following:

1. I create `Bitmap` from the resource
2. Draw that on `onDraw` method

Result is following: [image]

Code works with all other platform versions properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a NinePatchDrawable instead of a Bitmap?

Comment: Yes, that causes native crash, this has something to do this HW acceleration problems with ICS and 9 patches, but need to figure out some trick to get it work.

Comment: can you show us your onDraw method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the 9 patch image, same component works properly with other 9 patch drawable, weird thing though that the image works on other platforms.

The image worked properly in draw9patch tool. My graphics designer just opened original picture again in draw9patch, made the adjustments again, saved as 9 patch and voila, suddenly it worked.

Comment: So, is your problem resolved or you found any work around.. Please post your experience for others to benifit

Comment: Maybe the issue is the one "white spot" at the bottom?

Comment: When opening the images with draw9patch they are fine and this issue was not present in other OS versions, so I'm really confused what happened here, but making images again luckily solved this.